Assets folder does load on Angular 18
I was not able to load my images from the assets folder, I was using the Angular 18, after several atempts I was able to solve it.
Now on Angular 18 your assets folder needs to be on the path: public/
There is no needs to change angular.json
See it here ...

what path are you using? remember that should be like, e.g. <img src="assets/your-image.jpg"/>, NOT add a . or ../..or .... The assets folder generally is copy in the same directory where your index.html is created.

In Angular 18, the default folder for all assets is now outside the src directory and is called public. Previously, you would reference assets with a path like this:
Before:
<img src="assets/logo.png" alt="" srcset="">

Now:
<img src="/logo.png" alt="" srcset="">

Additionally, if you check the angular.json file, you will see that public is now the default folder for assets:
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "public"
  }
]



In my solution I putted all the images into the assets folder under the src directory. like

  src
  |_ assets
    |_ images
      |_ all images

Update the angular.json file:
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "/assets"
  }
],

Using in html component.
<img src="assets/images/image_name.jpg" alt="image_name">

Using in css component.
background: url(assets/images/image_name.jpg)no-repeat;

Note: You may rename of your directory rather than assets
