Assets (Images and Font Awesome Icons) Not Showing After Angular 18 Production Build
I'm experiencing an issue with my Angular 18 project after running a production build. The images in the assets folder and Font Awesome icons are not displaying when the application is deployed. Everything works perfectly in development mode, but after running ng build --prod, the assets seem to be missing.
I checked the build paths and confirmed that the paths in my HTML files and CSS are correct.
The assets are correctly referenced under the "assets" section.
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "/assets"
    },
    {
        "glob": "favicon.ico",
        "input": "src",
        "output": "/"
    },
    {
        "glob": "manifest.webmanifest",
        "input": "src",
        "output": "/"
    }
],

I used various build flags and options like --base-href and --output-hashing, but nothing seems to work.
The issue came in all browsers.
Angular Version: 18.0.0
Node Version: 20.9.0

Pls visit the solution link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78573019/assets-folder-does-load-on-angular-18/79234097#79234097

You Can check Your Browser Console & Analyzer to find Exact Problem Process , Also I Suggested You to Change the Production Configurations like this:
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "outputHashing": "all"
  }
}

Ensure that the deployment path is correctly set up on the server. Sometimes, the base href might not be properly configured. You can set the --base-href option to match the deployment path:
ng build --prod --base-href /your-base-href/

